# What would the properties of materials made of limpet teeth be?

Tags: physics, weapons, armors, materials

Limpet teeth are supposedly one of the strongest organically produced materials. Unfortunately producing this material in large enough quantities to use for much isn't currently possible.

However what if you had the ability to grow limpet teeth material in large quantities what applications would it have, and what might its macroscopic properties be?

I'm especially interested in what you might use it for in a medieval setting( such as for armor and weapons) provided you also had access to cheap means of producing other super-strong organically produced substances such as spider silk.

I'm thinking about using it in a fantasy setting but have very little idea what properties it would actually have other than the fact it is supposed to be even stronger than spider silk. Unfortunately whereas spider silk is produced in macroscopic quantities limpet teeth only seem to exist in microscopic amounts meaning you have to try to extrapolate its qualities.

I'm interested in how its qualities might compare to other materials like metal and what materials it might replace assuming access to most modern materials.

It's probably in your best interest to look up the paper where they tested limpet teeth. I can't possibly see you knowing how to answer the question otherwise.

Comment: Geothyte (that makes their teeth) is only about as strong as your standard calcites, so it wouldn't necessarily withstand weathering by impacts and would be easily worn down / weathered as a building material.  I'll give it a try to answer.

Comment: But why is it the case then that everyone's saying limpet teeth are the strongest natural material?

Comment: Here's one example http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31500883

Comment: Strongest *organic* material: it's a material made by animal that is as strong as stone.

Comment: Yeah but it's supposed to be stronger than spider silk, and spider silk is stronger than steel and kevlar.

Comment: This is a better link, I believe this actually contains the research done on limpet teeth http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/12/105/20141326

Comment: Keep in mind that "strength" is like "intelligence".  You can pretend to represent it by a simple number, say one thing is stronger than the other, but that's not really the case.  There are different kinds of strength, tensile vs compressive vs yield.  So Limpet Teeth can be "strong" in one axis without necessarily being good at building stuff with.  I mean Spider Silk is strong, but you aren't making swords out of it.

Comment: @DanSmolinske Yeah I know but given limpet teeth are really strong in certain ways they could probably have some applications if you could produce large amounts of the material.

Comment: Sure, but concrete is easier.  Industry blows away the harvesting of natural pruducts once society has the infrastructure for it.

Comment: @JDługosz In this setting people have the methods to produce large quantities of most biologically produced substances very cheaply but that isn't necessarily relevant.

Comment: They would use it instead of mining stone.  The "stronger than silk" part makes me think you don't know about different uses of "strong".  I seriously doubt a stone-like substance would score well in *tensile* strength.

Comment: Probably more applicable than the exact material of limpet teeth is the method of construction.  For instance, mussel shells are particularly tough protection.  This turns out in part due to how the material organization and layering of the nacre https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacre   The materials aren't particularly unique or tough but the way in which the organism puts it all together makes the shell quite tough & resilient.

Comment: I think that from a practical point of view the only way that limpet teeth could be useful is some point in the future where we have genetically engineered biomachines, and you want your machine to attach itself to something else semi-permanently.  In this context, you're really talking about either making artificial limpets, or altering limpets to have a different behaviour.  Neither involve harvesting the actual material itself, because the actual material isn't that amazing.  What works for the limpet is the way that it **uses** this material - outside that context it may not be useful.

Comment: @JDługosz Did you read the articles though, it does actually have a stronger tensile strength than spider silk they tested tensile strength specifically. Testing it was difficult given they were testing microscopic sizes scale.

Comment: Tensile strength testing on a milled-down fillement from a tooth: interesting. I still wonder about factors concerning scale, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this quote from the article linked to by @VakusDrake in the comments above (http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/12/105/20141326) sums it up (my emphasis):

"These observations highlight an absolute material tensile strength that is the highest recorded for a biological material, outperforming the high strength of spider silk currently considered to be the strongest natural material, and **approaching values comparable to those of the strongest man-made fibres**. "

So, there's your answer - the properties would be almost as strong as the strongest man-made fibres.  However, this is just on the small scale, and it might be that trying to make, for example, large cables out of the fibres is impractical.

Comment: and another reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limpet#Teeth (4.6 GPa in tension).  I assume that they are relatively hard too.  Limpet teeth are a mineral / organic composite material.  The quoted tensile strength is for the organic material portion.  The mineral inclusions possess much lower tensile strengths but much higher hardness.

Comment: By comparison, humans are working with composites with much higher material strengths.  For critical roles, we're using fibers like Boron Nitrides (inorganic) with tensile strength around 33 GPa in tension.  I don't know the hardness of limpet teeth but human composites concerned with hardness have a wide range of materials to use that are much harder than limpet teeth.  - what material is used for a specific application is determined using a cost / benefit analysis.

Comment: @Jim2B I'm assuming for the purposes of the question that people could selectively grow the portion of the structure with the most useful qualities. As for boron nitrates, if they're so much stronger than than steel and kevlar why aren't they used in place of those things, for many uses? Are they just way to expensive?

Comment: VakusDrake, they're tricky to work with and chemically reactive so they tend to react with the composite matrix.  This makes them expensive to use.  So Boron **Nitride** is only used when the benefit outweighs that expense.  We do use materials like sapphire, glass, carbon, etc. fibers for less demanding applications.  Also these fiber materials have very good tensile strength but usually don't have other bulk properties that we want, which is why they're combined in a composite.  It let's us mix & match material properties to suit our needs.

Comment: So since in the setting organically produced materials are cheap, the fact boron nitride is cheaper will likely not matter. I still think it might be interesting if you could use Boron Nitride for really expensive armor or something though...